# Which one should I prefer for releasing my custom non-managed properties?

Tags: iphone, core-data

-willTurnIntoFault or -didTurnIntoFault? I guess it's stupid to release properties in both of  them, so I must choose one. Which is the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is not "gone" when turned into a fault. It is reduced to its smallest size (just an empty object with an `-objectID`).  If you are doing something in the `-didTurnIntoFault` that causes a property to be touched you would reverse the fault which is bad.

If your clean up requires touching a property you should do it in the `-willTurnIntoFault`.  Otherwise it is pretty irrelevant which you choose.

Answer (score 1):

The former is invoked just BEFORE the object is turned into a fault, the latter just AFTER. What kind of custom non-managed properties are you referring to? The choice may depend on this.